# Не работает бургер

Tags: html, bootstrap, frontend

При ресайзе окна браузера не работает бургер, в чем может быть проблема?
код:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark ">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <h1 class="logo">.ONETOWN</h1>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-header" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav text-uppercase">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our works <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">about us</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">testimonials</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">subcribe</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form action="">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#staticBackdrop">JOIN <img src="./images/arrow-join.png">
                </button>

                

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
                    tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Modal title</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Understood</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: а при загрузке в нужном размере работает? тогда это значит, что слушатель js навешивается именно при загрузке только до определенного размера окна. При ресайзе, уже не срабатывает

Comment: дополнение: только что обнаружил, что все кнопки на сайте перестали работать((( отвечаю на вопрос  оно вообще не работает